# Rails 3 rendering iframe with raw()

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, iframe, render

So I am storing the whole embed code from youtube into my database and then outputting it like this.

```
<%= raw(people.video) %>
```

which outputs the general iframe tag copied from youtube:

```
<iframe src="foo" width=400 height=380></iframe>
```

the problem is that it actually displays that tag instead of embedding the video into the page itself. I can get around this just by storing the src in the database.... but this is part of a mini cms system and the site admins would find it much easier just to copy and past the embed code from youtube. Is there someway I can specify for the iframe to actually render instead of just spitting out the html on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `raw` method to render the HTML of a string, are you storing it that way?  You can also try the `RedCloth` gem - I was able to get this working like so:

```
<%= raw RedCloth.new(@page_content.content).to_html %>
```

Which allowed for my custom CMS to use the Textile markup
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textile_%28markup_language%29

I'm not 100% on what you're seeing, since raw should render HTML, but you might also try to include the embed tag using a JavaScript.write, since there are some issues related to Flash objects embedded in HTML vs JavaScript.

Let me know if this doesn't work, and if so, can you provide screenshots or copy what you're seeing on the page?

Comment: Thanks. I'll mark your answer as correct. It turns out that my jQuery CMS plugin was html sanitizing the open tags on the iframe. That being said I think I'll take a peek at redcloth :)